# Retrieve a value from serialized user meta key data and us in conditional

Tags: php, wordpress

OK so I haven't been able to work this out yet.

I have a user meta key that when I look at it in the database it contains:

```
a:1:{i:0;s:3:"Yes";}
```

So this is serialized data added by a form, a radio button to be exact. All I need to do is grab the "Yes" part for a conditional statement. I've tried almost everything I can think of to get this; I've used `get_user_meta()` trying to grab both an array or single attribute and trying the conditional:

```
$user_map_email = get_user_meta( $user->ID, $map_key, $single );
if ( $user_map_email == "Yes" )
```

I've tried to use `unserialize()` too:

```
 $user_map_email = unserialize($user_map_email[0]); 
    if ( $user_map_email[0] == "Yes" )
```

Plus every other thing I can think of. It must be such a simple thing to achieve but I've Googled and Googled and cannot see what I need.

I should note that this custom function I have is in **`functions.php`** in a child theme and hooks into `wp_login` so I don't know how to test what's in **$user_map_email** if I vardump or echo or print I don't see anything after I have logged in.

Any help very much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Very strange but now:

```
if ( $user_map_email[0] == "Yes" )
```

Is working fine. Maybe I didn't try this way without the serialization